# How to use the .on() method with the .each() method in jquery.?

Tags: jquery

I'm practicing on my own website's html and stumbled across this. I am sure it's a simple fix but want to know how to make it happen. I want all my list items or even just a specific class to be affected. I know the .each() method accesses all the elements matched in a jquery object. This code affectively accesses all the list items using the .each() method.
`$(function() {
    var $li = $('li');
    $li.hide().each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(700 * index).fadeIn(700)
    });
});`

This code doesn't have the .each() method here because I've tried placing it in multiple places and even tried wrapping the whole block in a new anonymous function after the short-hand document ready function.

```
$(function() {
var $list = $('.nav');
$list.on('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.0,
        paddingLeft: '+=80'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

});

This only works on the first class item with the attribute nav.
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `.each()` because `.on()` already applies to every item in the list.

Your code as written already works on every item with the `.nav` class. Below is a working code snippet to illustrate. You can click each of the three items and watch them disappear. If it's not working in your application, it must be due to some other issue. Check your jQuery object and make sure it really contains all the elements you think it does!

```js
$(function() {
var $list = $('.nav');
$list.on('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.0,
        paddingLeft: '+=80'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
First item
</div>

<div class="nav">
Second item
</div>

<div class="nav">
Third item
</div>
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Makes sense. I got it to work but it's triggered after the third click. Weird. It's probably something to do with the HTML. I'm new to coding and appreciate your feedback. Thanks again.

Comment: double-click* not third

Comment: @Cruhsh Is that happening when you try the code snippet in my answer? Or when you use the same code somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.nav', function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.0,
            paddingLeft: '+=80'
        }, 500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Are you wanting to remove all on single click? If so following will work.

```
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.nav', function() {
            $('.nav').animate({
                opacity: 0.0,
                paddingLeft: '+=80'
            }, 500, function() {
                $('.nav').remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but it still only grabs the first element in the matched set. I'm looking for a way to incorporate the .each() method with the .on() method.

Comment: shouldn't be, you must have problem in your other parts of codes i think.